# E over X => Expected Value

Tags: probability, expected-value

I stumbled upon this formula while reading about supervised machine learning.
I am wondering what the E over X means.

[image]

Does the E over X basically just mean the expected value of the random variable X? (=> E(X)) Or does it have a different meaning

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{E}$ symbol is usually used for [expectation values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). It means you are calculating the expected value with respect to the subscript variable

$$\mathbb{E}_X\rho(x, y) = \int x \rho(x,y)dx$$

Comment: Thanks, I was just confused by this new notation, that i have not seen before